# MySQL possible collisions when running many parallel inserts via multiple events

Tags: mysql

I have many events which can run at the same time. Their purpose is to insert rows at given times on a weekly schedule.

In my case there are 5 events which execute inserts at the same moment. Randomly some may fail. Here is what I have seen.

1. No inserts fail.
2. One insert fails.
3. Two inserts fail.

The code for these events is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO PublishRecord (TierKey, ProductId, PageKey, StoryKey, PublishDate, ChapterKey)
                        VALUES 
            
                (
                    'liesijznoo',
                    'prod_oOcEiHmKEh04Ag',
                    'lies5yw6p3',
                    'liyy27t7t7',
                    NOW(),
                    (
                        SELECT cid FROM (
                            SELECT PublishingQueue.ChapterKey as cid FROM PublishingQueue
                            LEFT JOIN Chapters ON Chapters.ChapterKey = PublishingQueue.ChapterKey
                            LEFT JOIN PublishRecord ON PublishRecord.ChapterKey = PublishingQueue.ChapterKey AND PublishRecord.TierKey = 'liesijznoo'
                            WHERE Chapters.StoryKey = 'liyy27t7t7' AND PublishRecord.TierKey IS NULL
                            ORDER BY Chapters.ChapterOrder ASC LIMIT 1
                        ) as c00
                    )
                )
```

Between these 5 events, the differences are the TierKey and the ChapterKey which gets selected.

That whole block for the chapter key is selecting an available chapter for publish.

I think this is an issue of collision because I created 5 events and had them run at 12:30 today in order to test it. Four of them succeeded and one failed. I then copied the code that failed (the above code) and I ran it again and this time it succeeded. So the only thing that makes sense is that there was an issue of collision during insertion.

What I'm not understanding is how there could be a collision on insert. The primary key is an auto incrmenting column. Would anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Hi there. Please add the relevant details about your question. Error message when the insert fails, the table structure definition for the one you are try to insert, any possible indexes involved with it, any possible triggers for that table. As of now your question is lacking details and will likely be closed. Thank you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos To answer your questions, there are no triggers, so I didn't list them. As stated, the indexes are auto incrementing. Finally, the new version of PHPMyAdmin doesn't seem to let me pull the slow log. It keeps saying I'm not logged in. But I'm very much so logged in.

Comment: The problem with phpAdmin is not with me being logged in, I have to enable the logs manually. I'll trigger the error again and add the logs here.

Comment: I'm having some trouble replicating again. The insertion failure does appear randomly, the last two times I tried all insertions were successful.

Comment: I can't replicate it now. I've tried many times :(

Comment: I'm going to try resolving this by having all events occur randomly within 10,000 milliseconds (+/-) from when they are supposed to occur so that there are a total 20,001 possible instances of when the inserts could occur. This should at least reduce the likelihood of future events inserting at the same time.

Comment: You are probably facing a Deadlock scenario for your inserts since you are trying to insert data on table `PublishRecord` by querying itself. But again, there is not enough information for us to give you meaningful help. You mentioned events automatically I thought this was an application thing, but it seems it is something within PHPMyAdmin? (based on your comments)

Comment: It's definitely something related to how this SQL statement is ran during the parallel events. There's no application involvement here since MySQL is handling the events. I'm using PHPMyAdmin only for the interface to quickly view the data.

Your comment on deadlocks is helpful, thank you. I'm doing some research on how those work. Maybe I can write this statement in such a way that doesn't require it to query the same table it's inserting into.

Comment: I cannot rewrite this to not query the table it's pushing into. Will turning off dead lock detection help?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to turn off deadlock, I might be wrong though I'm not exactly sure on that.

Comment: there's a setting called innodb_deadlock_detect

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_deadlock_detect

I turned it off, so far none of our users are complaining about issues and I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please note that Deadlock detection is there for a reason, this prevents inconsistencies from happening in your database. Now (i learned that you can disable it) you are accepting that you might get data inconsistencies on your table.

Comment: This ended up not being a solution anyways. I tried many more times and was able to reproduce the issue again. I re -enabled deadlock detection

Comment: I think the only solution that makes sense to me, is to not use MySQL events. Something where the node server handles the scheduling instead of MySQL.

Comment: If you are handling events consider an event driven approach like kafka. Also relying on existing data to insert new events seems odd, maybe review your design and check whether it would be possible to remove it (left join within the same table) if you think this way it might be possible to solve your problem without having to take out mysql events.

Comment: I need to know if a particular chapter already has a PublishRecord created for it, hence the left join

Comment: Additional information, when I run many of these but wait 100 miliseconds between each one, the error never occurs. The error only occurs when there are multiple mySQL events happening at the same time, querying the same chapters

Comment: To confirm, I ran 100 of these and spaced them out by only 1 millisecond. None of them failed.